# How to $ref for a property and make it 'required' as well in swagger 2.0?

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-2.0

Using go-swagger. I used the petstore example and edited the `NewPet` definition to this -

```
"NewPet": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "$ref":"#/definitions/name"
          },
          "tag": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
```

The definition of `name` being -

```
"name":{
            "type": "string"
    }
```

Generating the server removes the `required` validation from name. Is there something wrong here? Or is there another way to reuse the property definition?

Comment: Your spec is correct, so the issue is probably with the code generator. How did you generate the server?

Comment: `swagger generate server`

Comment: Open an issue in the [go-swagger repository](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/) on GitHub.